# Path animation ease (non-linear speed)?

Tags: animation

I created a very simple animation. I added a curve, and let the cube follow the path. It works, but the speed is constant. The pink line seem to be the position on the curve. Can I make this line a bezier instead of a straight line?

[image]
[image]

Here is the Blender file: https://gofile.io/?c=04aPgs

Answer (score 1):

Look in the properties panel of your *Graph Editor* (displayed with <kbd>N</kbd>), it looks like you've automatically generated a *Modifier* > *Generator*. You can modify it but you won't be able to add keyframes or manipulate handles. So:

- Close it.
- Create 2 keyframes at frame 1 and frame *n*:
- On the *Timeline*, put your cursor at frame 1 and give the *Evaluation Time* of your curve a value of 0 and insert a keyframe with <kbd>i</kbd>.
- On the *Timeline*, put your cursor at frame X (for example 50) and give the *Evaluation Time* of your curve a value of 100 (for example) and insert a keyframe with <kbd>i</kbd>.
- Now, in your *Graph Editor*, you can see the curve and handles that have been created, you can manipulate the handles, change their type with <kbd>V</kbd> or create new keyframes with <kbd>i</kbd>.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Seems that you have extrapolation in linear mode. Tochange that go to the graph editor, select you animated axis go to Channel > Extrapolation Mode > Constant Extrapolation. Also you animation has to have at least two keyframes.

[image: Graph Editor]

If that doesn't work please reupload the file because is down.

Comment: Extrapolation Mode is disabled. I am sorry about the link. It seems that File.IO deletes the file after one download, and I had downloaded it myself to see if it works. I uploaded the file to another site: https://gofile.io/?c=04aPgs